# Behaviour of <aura:handler name="change" ... /> when the containing object is set

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component with this change handler in it:

```
<aura:attribute name="amount" type="Decimal"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.amount}" action="{!c.handleChange}"/>
```

and this debug code added:

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('handleChange'
                + ' old ' + JSON.stringify(event.getParam('oldValue'))
                + ' new ' + JSON.stringify(event.getParam('value'))
                );
    ...
}
```

The `amount` value is one of the fields of an object - lets call it `x` - that is presented by the parent component.

What I am not expecting - probably too used to Angular's `$watch` - but getting is that when `x` is set again in the parent component as the result of an application event, the above change handler fires with `x` as the changed value. (The `oldValue` and `value` are the same as the content of `x` has not changed, it is just that `x` has been set again on the component.)

The [aura:valueChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm) documentation isn't too detailed in its definition of change. Looks like a change of an object will fire handlers on any field of the object and I guess that makes some sense. Any deeper insight or document references appreciated.